# A/B testing where success is not binary

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, ab-test, two-sample

I am a blogger testing different ad networks. The problem statement is actually quite simple:

Ad network 1: 100,000 pageviews. $460 ad revenue

Ad network 2: 100,000 pageviews. $428 ad revenue

Can I say with 95% certainty that ad network 1 is better than ad network 2?

The sub-questions are as follows:

- Am I asking the right question here? Or should I be asking "can I say with 95% certainty that ad network 1 is **10%** better than ad network 2?"
- In this scenario, is it appropriate to use a chi-squared test counting each dollar earned as a success? If we did that, it would look [like this](http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html#!460/100000;425/100000@95). So in dollars, there is no statistically significant difference. But if we change to each cent earned as a "success", then there *is* a significant difference. So this method doesn't seem to pass the smell test.
- The test that answers the question "Does the average value differ across two groups?" is the two-sample T-test. But I don't have individual data points here; just aggregates. Is there an alternative to the T-test that can be used for aggregate data?

Comment: Is there a linear relationship between the number of clicks on ads and revenue? What do you get then if you run a chi-square test?

Comment: Yes, there is a linear relationship between clicks and revenue. Total Revenue = # of clicks * revenue per click. I do have information on # of clicks for each ad network. If I run a chi-square test for # of clicks, then ad network 1 wins. However, it is also possible that ad network 2 has a higher revenue per click to counter its lower clickthrough rate. Ultimately, I want to optimize for revenue, not for # of clicks.

Comment: I came upon this a bit late. What is important is which networks can an advertiser hook onto that will reliably produce a reasonable profit. Then the question is how to find the cash / resources to run with all those networks at the same time. Regardless of any possible ranking. Spend time counting the profit rather than doing the stats. You can’t eat statistics......

Answer (score 1):

You have actually done most of the hard work with this problem already. The trick is to think about it in terms of a t-test.  When you compute the t-test, the inputs are: the means, the sample sizes and the standard deviations.  In your case, the means are fixed (0.0046 and 0.0048 per click), the sample size is fixed (100,000 and 100,000). You are finding no significant difference when you assume \$1 a click, but you are finding a significant difference when you assume \$0.01 per click.  This is because, for example, with your network 1, \$1 equates to a standard deviation of 0.06766746 where \$0.01 is 0.04983999, and the bigger the standard deviation the bigger the p-value (which is the complement of what you refer to as "certainty", which, sadly, is not really certainty, but read up on frequentest statistics if you wish to go down that rabbit hole).

Without knowing the standard deviations there is no way to test for your statistical significance, as your two alternative sets of assumptions demonstrate. But, what you can do is find some other bit of data that informs you about the likely ad revenue per click, as this will allow you to work out the range of possible standard deviations. For example, if the revenue is coming from store purchases and the cheapest thing in the store is \$1, then you have already worked out that there is no significant difference between the networks.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer doesn't help me decide which network is better. (Perhaps I didn't understand it correctly.) I do have data on number of clicks from each network, and by dividing revenue by # of clicks, I can find the _average_ revenue per click. But since all of this data is aggregate, I have no way (that I know of) to compute variance/std. dev. So then I assume I can't use a standard t-test. So I don't know what to make of the results of the experiment.

Comment: Tim is suggesting you have to find ways to estimate the standard deviation (Eg looking up industry stats for network). I am surprised you cannot get standard deviation output (also aggregate).  What about using standard deviation of different days/hours?

Comment: seanv507 is spot on. If you cannot find a way of approximating the likely values of the standard deviations, you do not have enough data to draw any conclusion.

Comment: @Tim Then would it be wrong to use a chi-squared test? Let's keep the same problem but with larger numbers. Say both versions A and B get 1 million pageviews each. Version A earns 5,000 dollars and version B earns 3,000 dollars. Intuition tells me I have a large enough sample to conclude that version A is the winner. What statistical tests can replace intuition for such a problem statement? [I see no option other than chi-square but wanted to confirm.]

Comment: Your chi-square test is really just an approximation of a t-test. I do not think it matters so much which one you do. But, even if you had a sample of a trillion and version A was 5,000 and version B was 3,000, it is still possible to get a statistically insignificant result (e.g., if the 5,000 was a single purchase and the 3,000 was a single purchase).

Comment: @Tim Good point. In this case, however, the revenue is accrued 1 click at a time and each click is usually between $.10 and \$1. If a chi-square test is an approximation of a t-test, then that gives me the green light to use it. I'm not finding any other options anyway.